Breaking out of recursion in LaTeX macro using Lua?
Thus far I have:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[legalpaper, landscape, margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{luacode}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newcommand{\typeset}[1]{#1\par\hphantom{0000000 }\vtop{%\directlua{tpwsid =""}
\evaluate{#1}}}

\newcommand{\evaluate}[1]{% 
\hskip0sp\vtop
{%
%\directlua{if (string.find(tpwsid,#1) and #1~="1090022") then tex.sprint("\\relax") else tex.sprint("\\textcolor{red}{1090037 EMERGENCY PURCHASED SURFACE}\\par\\hphantom{0000000 }\\vtop{\\evaluate{1090037}}") end}
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1090022}}{\textcolor{red}{1090037 EMERGENCY PURCHASED SURFACE}\par\hphantom{0000000 }{\vtop{\evaluate{1090037}}}}{}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1090022}}{               {1090369 PERMANENT PURCHASED SURFACE}\par\hphantom{0000000 }{\vtop{\evaluate{1090369}}}}{}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1090022}}{               {1090775 PERMANENT PURCHASED SURFACE}\par\hphantom{0000000 }{\vtop{\evaluate{1090775}}}}{}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1090026}}{               {1090022 PERMANENT PURCHASED SURFACE}\par\hphantom{0000000 }{\vtop{\evaluate{1090022}}}}{}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1090026}}{               {1090079 PERMANENT PURCHASED SURFACE}\par\hphantom{0000000 }{\vtop{\evaluate{1090079}}}}{}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1090026}}{               {1156469 PERMANENT PURCHASED SURFACE}\par\hphantom{0000000 }{\vtop{\evaluate{1156469}}}}{}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1090063}}{\textcolor{red}{1090069 EMERGENCY PURCHASED SURFACE}\par\hphantom{0000000 }{\vtop{\evaluate{1090069}}}}{}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1090079}}{               {1090022 PERMANENT PURCHASED SURFACE}\par\hphantom{0000000 }{\vtop{\evaluate{1090022}}}}{}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1090079}}{               {1090043 PERMANENT PURCHASED SURFACE}\par\hphantom{0000000 }{\vtop{\evaluate{1090043}}}}{}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1090079}}{               {1090063 PERMANENT PURCHASED SURFACE}\par\hphantom{0000000 }{\vtop{\evaluate{1090063}}}}{}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1090079}}{               {1090078 PERMANENT PURCHASED SURFACE}\par\hphantom{0000000 }{\vtop{\evaluate{1090078}}}}{}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1090079}}{               {1090089 PERMANENT PURCHASED SURFACE}\par\hphantom{0000000 }{\vtop{\evaluate{1090089}}}}{}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1090079}}{               {1090089 PERMANENT PURCHASED SURFACE}\par\hphantom{0000000 }{\vtop{\evaluate{1090089}}}}{}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1090079}}{               {1090140 PERMANENT PURCHASED SURFACE}\par\hphantom{0000000 }{\vtop{\evaluate{1090140}}}}{}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1090079}}{               {1460073 PERMANENT PURCHASED SURFACE}\par\hphantom{0000000 }{\vtop{\evaluate{1460073}}}}{}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1156469}}{               {3066215 PERMANENT PURCHASED GROUND }\par\hphantom{0000000 }{\vtop{\evaluate{3066215}}}}{}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1156469}}{               {1156477 PERMANENT PURCHASED GROUND }\par\hphantom{0000000 }{\vtop{\evaluate{1156477}}}}{}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1090001}}{               {1090078 PERMANENT PURCHASED SURFACE}\par\hphantom{0000000 }{\vtop{\evaluate{1090078}}}}{}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1090078}}{               {1156469 PERMANENT PURCHASED GROUND }\par\hphantom{0000000 }{\vtop{\evaluate{1156469}}}}{}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1090078}}{               {1460073 PERMANENT PURCHASED SURFACE}\par\hphantom{0000000 }{\vtop{\evaluate{1460073}}}}{}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1090043}}{\textcolor{red}{1090074 EMERGENCY PURCHASED GROUND }\par\hphantom{0000000 }{\vtop{\evaluate{1090074}}}}{}%
%\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1460073}}{               {1090078 PERMANENT PURCHASED SURFACE}\par\hphantom{0000000 }{\vtop{\evaluate{1090078}}}}{}%
%\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1460073}}{               {1090127 PERMANENT PURCHASED SURFACE}\par\hphantom{0000000 }{\vtop{\evaluate{1090127}}}}{}%
%\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1460073}}{\textcolor{red}{1460046 EMERGENCY PURCHASED SURFACE}\par\hphantom{0000000 }{\vtop{\evaluate{1460046}}}}{}%
%\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1460073}}{\textcolor{red}{1150011 EMERGENCY PURCHASED SURFACE}\par\hphantom{0000000 }{\vtop{\evaluate{1150011}}}}{}%
%\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1460073}}{               {1150035 PERMANENT PURCHASED SURFACE}\par\hphantom{0000000 }{\vtop{\evaluate{1150035}}}}{}%
%\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1460073}}{               {1150098 PERMANENT PURCHASED SURFACE}\par\hphantom{0000000 }{\vtop{\evaluate{1150098}}}}{}%
%\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1460073}}{\textcolor{red}{1150834 EMERGENCY PURCHASED SURFACE}\par\hphantom{0000000 }{\vtop{\evaluate{1150834}}}}{}%
%\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1460073}}{               {1156469 PERMANENT PURCHASED SURFACE}\par\hphantom{0000000 }{\vtop{\evaluate{1156469}}}}{}%
%\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1460073}}{               {1230881 PERMANENT PURCHASED SURFACE}\par\hphantom{0000000 }{\vtop{\evaluate{1230881}}}}{}%
%\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1460073}}{               {1236371 PERMANENT PURCHASED SURFACE}\par\hphantom{0000000 }{\vtop{\evaluate{1236371}}}}{}%
%\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1460073}}{               {1460020 PERMANENT PURCHASED SURFACE}\par\hphantom{0000000 }{\vtop{\evaluate{1460020}}}}{}%
%\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1460073}}{               {1460028 PERMANENT PURCHASED SURFACE}\par\hphantom{0000000 }{\vtop{\evaluate{1460028}}}}{}%
%\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1460073}}{               {1460033 PERMANENT PURCHASED SURFACE}\par\hphantom{0000000 }{\vtop{\evaluate{1460033}}}}{}%
%\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1460073}}{               {1460046 PERMANENT PURCHASED SURFACE}\par\hphantom{0000000 }{\vtop{\evaluate{1460046}}}}{}%
%\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1460073}}{\textcolor{red}{1460046 EMERGENCY PURCHASED SURFACE}\par\hphantom{0000000 }{\vtop{\evaluate{1460046}}}}{}%
%\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1460073}}{\textcolor{red}{1460046 EMERGENCY PURCHASED SURFACE}\par\hphantom{0000000 }{\vtop{\evaluate{1460046}}}}{}%
%\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1460073}}{\textcolor{red}{1460492 EMERGENCY PURCHASED SURFACE}\par\hphantom{0000000 }{\vtop{\evaluate{1460492}}}}{}%
%\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1460073}}{               {1460841 PERMANENT PURCHASED SURFACE}\par\hphantom{0000000 }{\vtop{\evaluate{1460841}}}}{}%
%\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1460073}}{               {1460968 PERMANENT PURCHASED SURFACE}\par\hphantom{0000000 }{\vtop{\evaluate{1460968}}}}{}%
%\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1460073}}{               {1466599 PERMANENT PURCHASED SURFACE}\par\hphantom{0000000 }{\vtop{\evaluate{1466599}}}}{}%
%\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1460073}}{               {1466599 PERMANENT PURCHASED SURFACE}\par\hphantom{0000000 }{\vtop{\evaluate{1466599}}}}{}%
%\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1460073}}{               {1466599 PERMANENT PURCHASED SURFACE}\par\hphantom{0000000 }{\vtop{\evaluate{1466599}}}}{}%
%\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1460073}}{               {1466599 PERMANENT PURCHASED SURFACE}\par\hphantom{0000000 }{\vtop{\evaluate{1466599}}}}{}%
%\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1460073}}{               {1466618 PERMANENT PURCHASED SURFACE}\par\hphantom{0000000 }{\vtop{\evaluate{1466618}}}}{}%
%\directlua{tpwsid = tpwsid.." "..#1}
}
}

\begin{document}%
\typeset{1090026}
\end{document}

which works:

until one uncomments a line which creates a circular call/endless/infinite loop.
My idea to address this was to use Lua scripting, adding a variable tpwsid which would hold each PWS ID (the seven digit numbers) which had been typeset thus far, adding the package
\usepackage{luacode}

then adding
\directlua{tpwsid = tpwsid.." "..#1}

in at the end of the \evaluate... macro definition and then for each line adding a check:
along the lines of:
\\directlua{if (string.find(tpwsid,#1) and #1~="1090022") then tex.sprint("\\relax") else tex.sprint("\\textcolor{red}{1090037 EMERGENCY PURCHASED SURFACE}\\par\\hphantom{0000000 }\\vtop{\\evaluate{1090037}}") end}

and of course:
\usepackage{luacode}

but it's not breaking out of the recursion with just the one call:
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [text input levels=15].
\evaluate ...0 }\\vtop{\\evaluate{1090037}}") end}
                                                   \ifthenelse {\equal 
{#1}{...

l.65 \typeset{1090026}
                
 8324 words of node memory still in use:
   92 hlist, 1 rule, 42 disc, 45 local_par, 31 dir, 134 glue, 59 kern, 15 penal
ty, 603 glyph, 139 attribute, 48 glue_spec, 139 attribute_list, 60 temp, 1 writ
e, 29 pdf_colorstack nodes
   avail lists: 1:1,4:1
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on 1090026working_LUA.log.

(I've added these lines in commented out to the MWE)
My apologies for the mix of Plain TeX and LaTeX (suggestions on better form LaTeX would also be welcome).
I tried nested if calls but the errors were even more bizarre....

As expected, the solution is to use a variable to keep track of which have been typeset, and then, check each entry to see if it has already been done, and at the end, zero out the variable to start afresh:
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[a0paper, margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\directlua{tpwsid =""}
\newcommand{\addpws}[1]{\directlua{tpwsid = tpwsid.." "..#1}}%

\NewDocumentEnvironment{autoFit}{O{\linewidth}}{\noindent\maxsizebox{\linewidth}{!}\bgroup%
    \begin{varwidth}{2\linewidth}% Upper bound on the width of the text
    }{\end{varwidth}\egroup}

\newsavebox\boxt

\newcommand{\octothorpe}{\#}

\newcommand{\typeset}[1]{
{\evaluate{#1}}%
\clearpage\directlua{tpwsid = ""}}%

\newcommand{\z}{\hskip0pt}

\newcommand{\evaluate}[1]{#1~% 
\vtop
{%\vskip0pt%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1}  }{\directlua{if (string.find(tpwsid,"11002"  )) then tex.sprint("\\relax") else tex.sprint("{\\z                 {PERMANENT PURCHASED SURFACE WASHINGTON COUNTY 002            }\\par\\hphantom{ }\\vtop{\\addpws{11002}  \\evaluate{9996507}}}") end}}{}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{564}}{\directlua{if (string.find(tpwsid,"5642002")) then tex.sprint("\\relax") else tex.sprint("{\\z{PERMANENT PURCHASED SURFACE SUEZ WATER DELAWARE 002}\\par\\hphantom{ }\\vtop{\\addpws{5642002}\\evaluate{1230012}}}") end}}{}%
...
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{7670076}}{\directlua{if (string.find(tpwsid,"76700769005")) then tex.sprint("\\relax") else tex.sprint("{\\z\\textcolor{red}{EMERGENCY PERMITTED PURCHASED SURFACE HANOVER INTERCONNECT 005}\\par\\hphantom{ }\\vtop{\\addpws{76700769005}\\evaluate{7670100}}}") end}}{}%

  }\vskip6pt%
}

\begin{document}%
\typeset{1}%
\typeset{564}%
\typeset{1274}%
...
\end{document}

